# Unspecified Error when sending document on Go Live

Tags: docusignapi

I have an active and functional Go Live account. When I use it in my development environment `(localhost)` I can retrieve the token and send the envelope to the recipients. When I try to use it in the production environment, I can recover the token but I cannot send the envelope. It returns the error to me:

```
POST https://na2.docusign.net:8822/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxXXXxxXXxx/envelopes

TraceToken: 03e22f1f-0454-42a5-9e71-337ebf1dd39f
Timestamp: 2020-02-07T19:28:16.4891717Z

Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [omitted]
Host: na2.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/2.0.1/php
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-DocuSign-SDK: PHP
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
x-forwarded-for: 34.73.119.92


400 BadRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 82
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 03e22f1f-0454-42a5-9e71-337ebf1dd39f

{"errorCode":"UNSPECIFIED_ERROR","message":"Non-static method requires a target."}
```

I don't think it's a coding problem because it works well in the development environment

Comment: Silly question, but is that the _entire_ API log, or did you cut the body of the call out?

Comment: This is the entire log

Comment: which version of the PHP SDK/library are you using?

Comment: @InbarGazit I'm using version 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the entire API log, the issue is that your API call does not have a body. Since you're using an SDK, this means that an empty or otherwise invalid EnvelopeDefinition was passed into your CreateEnvelope method.

Comment: I tested it and the Envelope Definition is not empty. As I commented, if I change the credentials to sandbox the emails are triggered normally, so I doubt it is a code problem.

Comment: You can try using a network tracking tool such as Fiddler to capture the API traffic your application is generating, but the short answer is that your application is making a call to DocuSign without a body.

Comment: That was really the problem. For some reason, the 'json_encode' function was returning empty text instead of data formatted in json. I made some changes for it to format and work. Many thanks for the reply!